# cmsplugin-zinnia throwing a No module namedEntryMenu

Tags: django, django-cms, django-syncdb

I've got an issue when trying to run python manage.py syncdb. I am building a site with django-CMS and adding cmsplugin-zinnia for blog features. But this is coming up and I can not figure out why, looking at the code EntryMenu exists.

`raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError cmsplugin_zinnia.menu.EntryMenu: No module named EntryMenu`

I've done a lot of Googling and don't see any posts on this same issue. If you can point me in the right direction I'd be greatful. Thanks!

**Settings:**

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # 'tinymce',
    'html5boilerplate',
    'raven.contrib.django',
    'robots',
    'south',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'reversion',
    'templateland',
    'tagging',
    'zinnia',
    'cmsplugin_zinnia',

    'contralogy.apps.frontend',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',

    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.teaser',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',

    'cmsplugin_zinnia.menu.EntryMenu',
    'cmsplugin_zinnia.menu.CategoryMenu',
    'cmsplugin_zinnia.menu.TagMenu',
    'cmsplugin_zinnia.menu.AuthorMenu',

    #admin tool
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',

    'filer',

)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('contralogy/home.html', 'Home Page'),
    ('contralogy/template_1.html', 'Template One'),
)

ZINNIA_ENTRY_BASE_MODEL = 'cmsplugin_zinnia.placeholder.EntryPlaceholder'
```

**pip freeze**

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.3.1
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PIL==1.1.7
South==0.7.5
-e git://github.com/Fantomas42/cmsplugin-zinnia.git@3790581ae8f669ad37dcdaedf86ee6ca61e1d06b#egg=cmsplugin_zinnia-dev
django-admin-tools==0.4.0
django-appconf==0.5
-e git://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia.git@12e825ff3d25d47d43882db2ea83961038372de8#egg=django_blog_zinnia-dev
django-classbasedsettings==1.0b2
django-classy-tags==0.3.4.1
django-cms==2.3.3
django-compressor==1.1.2
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
django-filer==0.8.5
django-mptt==0.5.2
django-reversion==1.5.1
django-robots==0.8.1
django-sekizai==0.6.1
django-tagging==0.3.1
django-tinymce==1.5.1b2
django-xmlrpc==0.1.4
easy-thumbnails==1.1
html5lib==0.95
pyparsing==1.5.6
pytz==2012h
raven==2.0.0
simplejson==2.4.0
```

If there is more needed to understand let me know. Thank you in advance!